# Regualr expression to validate embed tag

Tags: embed

I have a text box, for the user to paste an embed tag inside it, but i want to validate, weather a user is not entering any other code other than an embed tag, hence i need to validate an embed tag.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the format of what you want allowed to be entered?

Comment: My customer's can have their videos uploaded on youtube,i want to give them  facility, where they can embed the those videos into my site, so that i can directly run their videos in my site, but i want to check whether they are entering an embed tag only or some thing else in my text box.

Comment: So why not just accept the url of their youtube video and put it in an embed yourself?

Answer (score 1):

```
\s*(https?://)www.youtube(-nocookie)?.com/(?:v|embed)/[\p{L}\p{N}]+[\p{L}\p{N}\p{Zs}.#@$%+&;:_~,?=!/-]*\s*
```

I took the liberty to remove unnecessary capture groups, escapes and characters.

Although I personally would use something like:

```
\s*(https?://www.youtube(?:-nocookie)?.com/(?:v|embed)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).*)
```

That puts the entire youtube URL in match group 0 and the video id in match group 1. Also it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to use unicode properties when youtube's URLs don't contain unicode characters.
Demo: http://rubular.com/r/jv4zO9ys2L